# Is Qt 4.8.2 binary available?

Tags: qt, build, paraview

Can I download the Qt 4.8.2 binary for Linux anywhere?  I am building ParaView, which does not work with Qt 5.x.

Comment: here's the source code at least: http://download.qt-project.org/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.2/

Comment: Most distros will have Qt 4.8.x packages for some x, so check your distro unless you need 4.8.2 specifically.

Comment: if its compatible you can at least try the latest Qt4 version (4.8.5)

Comment: You don't need 4.8.2, any recent 4.x version will work. Your linux distribution should have Qt 4 packages available for installation.

Comment: I don't have root access on the machine, so I can't use yum, as far a I know.  How should I install it?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Kuba Ober, Qt 4.8.2 is [source code and binary compatible](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Version-Compatibility) to Qt 4.8.5 (and Qt 4.8.6). that means, that you can execute a program with Qt 4.8.5, that was linked against Qt. 4.8.2.

Comment: Can I donwload the 4.x binaries somewhere?

Comment: You can download your distribution packages and unpack them without installing them. What is the contents of your /etc/issue file?

Comment: CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m

Comment: just download the rpm from [rpmfind](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=qt&system=centos&arch=) and extract the content